# DFT Hartree Potential with Periodic Boundary Conditions

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, potential, density, density-functional-theory

Suppose we have a periodic crystal. Let $\rho(r)$ be the electronic density, and let $a$ be the lattice vectors. Due to the periodicity, the Hartree potential can be written as
\begin{align}
V_H(r)&=\int \frac{\rho(r')}{|r-r'|} d^3r'\\
&=\sum_a\int_{\Omega(a)}\frac{\rho(r'+a)}{|r-r'|} d^3(r'+a)\\
&=\sum_a\int_\Omega \frac{\rho{r'}}{|r-r'+a|} d^3r'\tag{1}
\end{align}
Here, the integral $\int$ is over all of space while the integral $\int_\Omega$ is over one unit cell.

DFT codes would calculate this by solving the Poisson's equation with periodic boundary conditions
\begin{align}
\nabla^2V_H(r)&=-4\pi\rho(r)+\mathrm{P.B.C.}\tag{2}\\
V_H(G)&=\frac{4\pi\rho(G)}{|G|^2}
\end{align}

How is the terms $a\ne 0$ accounted for in (1)? Is it automatically accounted for by the periodic boundary condition in (2)?